# Downloading a file in parts from different computers simultaneously

Tags: java, networking, p2p, jxta

I want to create a application that can communicate to the different computers and can download file from there. If there exist the same file in different computers then the file will be downloaded in parts simultaneously from these computers, which will make my download speed a lot faster.  How can I implement that using JXTA?

Comment: What protocol do you intend to use? HTTP or something else?

Comment: Err, did you create a new account to ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370425/how-to-download-same-file-distributed-in-different-computers-in-java)?

Comment: No...May be any one of my team mate cud have posted the question...let me check

Comment: can you suggest me how can it be done using jxta???

Comment: So what is the question here exactly? If you are asking for a JXTA tutorial? Or to for someone to implement for you?

Comment: i am asking the tutorial for splitting the file and sending using java over jxta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JXTA framework will help you exchange files, but the splitting in parts will have to be done by your application. I suggest you take a look at bidirectional pipes. Each messages could be tagged with a part number. Another solution could be using queries and send bits in answers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to implement a new Bittorrent client?

Comment: Sounds like a vanilla download "accelerator" such as [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/).

Comment: @guido garcla: Actually i am creating an application like a bit torrent but not exactly. I am using JXTA for peer to peer communication and had made a simple file transfer using it. I wanted to improve that to make the transfer of same files which are displayed and are occuring in different peers simultaneously. I think this will give me a lot more speed...I dont know how that can be implemented??

Comment: @steve: I think download accelerators just communicate with one peer/server and downloads the whole file from the server in parts and later joins it. my problem is that how can i download those different parts from different peers simultaneously and join it later on..